# Writing in a Word Document Header Using Excel VBA

Tags: excel, vba, ms-word, header

I'm creating a button in an excel sheet that generates a report in Word. So far, so good except I'm trying to have a header in the document that looks like this:
[image]

but it ends up just looking like this:
[image]

where it just comes up as this weird extra window at the bottom of my document and it says page 3, when there is only two pages of the document (or there only should be two pages)
my code is:

```
'Header

  With Wordapp
   .activeDocument.Bookmarks("Header").Select
   .Selection.TypeText Text:="CFD Analysis of Antenna EPA "
   .Selection.MoveRight Count:=1
   .Selection.TypeText Text:=today
   .Selection.MoveRight Count:=1
   .Selection.TypeText Text:=antennamanu & " " & modnum
  End With
```

Comment: Make sure the document is in the "Print view" (and not the "Draft" view, which we're seeing in the screen shot). Comment out the code in the `With` block and try this test: `.ActiveDocument.Bookmarks("Header").Range.Text = "Test"` Does this appear "normally"?

Comment: @Cindy the test works! but how do I make it have different lines (both left and right aligned) like the first picture?

Answer (score 0):

The behavior shown in the screen shot of the question is due to use the `Select` method. This separate Header pane, in the Draft view, comes from the days of Word 2.0, where WYSIWYG wasn't available for headers, footers, comments and similar things.

Instead of using `Select`, working directly with `Range` objects will avoid the problem. The code in the question can be altered along these lines:

```
'Header
  Dim rngHeader as Word.Range 'or Object if this is late-binding
  With Wordapp
   Set rngHeader = .ActiveDocument.Bookmarks("Header").Range
   rngHeader.Text ="CFD Analysis of Antenna EPA " & vbTab & _
                    today & vbCr & antennamanu & " " & modnum
  End With
```

In the original code, the document apparently has a TAB and a Paragraph character.  So `Selection.MoveRight` is moving to the tab stop, and then to the next paragraph. The above code writes those as it goes, so these characters should be removed from the report template being used.

Comment: I think you’ve forgotten to include the tabs.